# Bootstrap collapse with dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with jQuery vertical dropdown menu; When I hover menu item, dropped menu is 'cutting' in bootstrap collapse. Could you help me with that? jQuery menu is taken from
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm#ajax
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that the CSS property `overflow:hidden;` has been set on either the container of your *jQuery* menu or one of that container's parent containers.

Without seeing the HTML you're working on it's impossible to say which but you'll need to find which HTML element has the `overflow` setting set to `hidden` and then set it to `visible`. You may need to do that for more than one element depending on the structure of your HTML.

Hope that helps.

Comment: exactly what I need. Added in .collapse.in {  overflow: visible;

Answer (score 0):

I know that prolem.

[image]

You can do:

1. Make folder name: `images`
2. Open `ddsmoothmenu.js` and type :

[image]

Note:
in folder images you have:

`right.png`,`left.png`,`down.png`